# How to insert the data from excell file to Mysql table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to insert the data from given excel sheet to mysql table.I am using PHP 5.0.If it is not possible is there is any option for convert excel to CSV then Inert into Mysql table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) or [ExcelExplorer](http://www.eephp.com/) to read Excel files in PHP.

Comment: I want to store it when the user upload the excell file from the system to site.